# Simple jQuery Contextual Menu Click Problem

Tags: jquery, navigation

I'm absolutely trying to steer clear of plugins for this, I want something lightweight and simple. This is as far as I have gotten on a contextual menu. I can click on the `li.dd a` and it reveals the `ul`, and when I click on it again it hides the `ul`. What it doesn't let me do is click on anchors in the `ul`. Instead of linking to that anchor it hides the menu. Anything I need to do differently?

```
html:
  <ul class="tools">
    <li class="dd"><a href="#" class="bnt">Tools</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="last">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

SASS:
  .tools
    font-weight: bold
    margin: 12px 0 -12px !important
    text-align: right
    a.bnt
      border: #404041 1px solid
      color: #fff !important
      padding: 6px 15px
    ul
      background-color: #fff
      margin-top: 20px !important
      margin-left: 106px !important
      width: 210px
      a
        border-bottom: #cfcfcf 1px solid
        color: #666
        display: block
        font-weight: normal
        padding: 6px 20px
        text-align: left
        &:hover
          background-color: #000
          color: #fff
        &.last
          border-bottom: none

jQuery:
$(function() {
  $(".dd").toggle(
    function(){ 
      $("ul", this).fadeIn("fast");
      $(this).addClass('on');
          }, 
    function(){ $("ul", this).fadeOut("fast"); $(this).removeClass('on'); }
  );
});
```

Comment: I've tried plugins but they add extra markup that I don't want, plus some just don't do it exactly how I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you attached the click event to the list item that contains the anchors, that's to be expected. You can either put a dedicated element to handle the toggle events, move the event to the first anchor outside of the inner list-items, or stop propagation of click events on the anchors -

```
$('.dd li a').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Cool, worked like a charm, and I also changed the selector to not use Shizzle. Thanks!